# How can I group words of a String based on a list of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, grouping

i have a list of words and a string and i want to create a new list if same words of a list are in the string and the next word of the string is also present in string it will append them store them as a new element in the list.

```
keyword_list = ['individual', 'fixed', 'treatments', 'deposit', 'health',
                'millions', 'panic', 'decision', 'policy', 'insurance', 'account']

string1 = 'i want to buy individual insurance policy and you can get upto 2 millions for the cover do not panic i also want to open fixed deposit account'

new_list = ['individual insurance policy',
            'millions', 'panic', 'fixed deposit account']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the elements based on their presence in the `keyword_list` and join the groups with `" "`.

```
>>> data = 'i want to buy individual insurance policy and you can get upto 2 millions for the cover do not panic i also want to open fixed deposit account'
>>> keyword_list = ['individual', 'fixed', 'treatments', 'deposit', 'health',
...                 'millions', 'panic', 'decision', 'policy', 'insurance', 'account']
```

Now, let's convert the `keyword_list` to a set so that the lookups will be faster.

```
>>> keys = set(keyword_list)
```

Now, let's group the words in `data` based on their presence in `keys`, like this

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [" ".join(grp) for res, grp in groupby(data.split(), keys.__contains__) if res]
['individual insurance policy', 'millions', 'panic', 'fixed deposit account']
```

For every element in the collection passed to `groupby`, in our case it is `data.split()`, the `keys.__contains__` function will be called. And based on the result of that function call, the groups will be formed. Since we are interested only in the items which are present in `keys`, we filter with `if res` in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

'''
This is the answer which i come up with can we improve it i am not getting a suitable answer
'''

speech = "who should buy an individual health insurance policy even if you are young and healthy it is a wise decision to have an individual health insurance policy"

keyword =['individual','health','insurance','deposit','fixed','account','policy','young']

new_key=[]

speech_list = speech.split()

for i in range(len(speech_list)-1):

```
if speech_list[i] in keyword:

    word = speech_list[i]

    for x in range(i+1,len(speech_list)-1):

        if speech_list[x] in keyword:

            word+=" "+speech_list[x]

        else:

            break;

    new_key.append(word)
```

print(new_key)

'''CODE_OUTPUT - ['individual health insurance policy' , 'health insurance policy' , 'insurance policy' , 'policy' , 'young' , 'individual health insurance', 'health insurance', 'insurance']'''

'''EXPECTED_OUTPUT - ['individual health insurance policy' , 'young', 'individual health insurance' ]'''